# Replace a list of items from a .txt file

Tags: python-3.x, list, replace, split

We have a text file named as 'text.txt' and it has some string (poem written in multiple lines) in it. Also we have a list = [ 'donkey','he','I']. These items are present in the string with in the text file. Now I want to replace above items from string with '#####'?

with open("text.txt","r") as f:
`your text`read=f.read()
`your text`x=['donkey','he','I']
`` your text`words=read.split() `` your text`for item in x:` your text`for i in words:` your text`if item == i:` your text`new=read.replace(i,'####') with open("text.txt","w") as g:` your text``write = g.write(new)
`your text`print(write)

Result:- Program execute without any error.

####f #### had a donkey
And he would not go,
Would #### wallop him?
No, no, no.

##### would find a little hay

And give him some corn,
Then he would be the best donkey
That ever was born..

I have used split() funtion to iterate through words still 'I' in word 'If' replaced with ####, only I from the list is replaced not other items from the list.

expected result:-

If #### had a ####
And #### would not go,
Would #### wallop him?
No, no, no.
I would find a little hay
And give him some corn,
Then #### would be the best ####
That ever was born.

What could be best possible soltuion for the same? Can we replace items using file io funtion only one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what i would do:

```
replacer = [ 'donkey','he','i']

f = open("text.txt", "r")
x = f.readlines()
f.close()
rewrite = []
for i in x:
    line = i.split()
    rline = ''
    for j in line:
        if j.lower() in replacer:
            rline += "#### "
        else:
            rline += j+" "
    rewrite.append(rline + "\n")

f = open("text.txt", "w")
f.writelines(rewrite)
```

There might be a better way to do this but this works just fine

 if you want you can ask for explanation on any line you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I hope this satisfies your problem,

```
import re

arr = [ 'donkey','he','i']

f = open('text.txt', "r")
x = f.read()
rewrite = []


for i in x.split():
    flag = True
    for j in arr:
        ans = re.fullmatch(j+"\W?", i.lower())
        if ans!=None:
            flag = False
            rewrite.append('#### ')
    if flag:
        rewrite.append(i+" ")
    


f = open("text.txt", "w")
f.writelines(''.join(rewrite))
```

input:

```
If I had a donkey,
That wouldn't go.
Do you think I'd beat him?
Oh, no, no!
I'd put him in a barn,
And give him some corn,
The best little donkey,
That ever was born!
```

output:

```
If #### had a #### That wouldn't go. Do you think I'd beat him? Oh, no, no! I'd put him in a barn, And give him some corn, The best little #### That ever was born!
```